# If the universal cover of $X$ is contractible, then $\pi_n(X) = {0}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I know that a covering $p:X\to Y$ is universal if the space $X$ is simply connected.

But I'm not sure how do I prove that If the universal cover of X is contractible, then $\pi_n(X) = {0}$ for $n>1$

I tried searching a little bit about the proof of this claim  but everywhere it is just claimed without a proof...

Can someone please explain me how can I prove this?

Comment: Let $\tilde{X}$ be the universal cover of $X$, then since $\tilde{X}\simeq\{*\}$, we know that $\pi_n(\tilde{X})$ is trivial for all $n\ge 1$. Then, since the universal covering map induces isomorphisms on all higher homotopy groups, it is immediate that $\pi_n(X)=0$ for all $n\ge 2$.

Comment: ^ This is right, and the proof of that isomorphism is the long exact sequence on homotopy groups. The fiber, being a discrete space (since we're talking about a covering space) has trivial higher homotopy groups.

Comment: `$\to$` or `$\rightarrow$` manufactures a function arrow $\to$.

Comment: The reference to point to is Hatcher, Proposition 4.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/186343/591889

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you! Yes it does @User !